# Displaying multiple images side by side with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a program for facial recognition and now I have to make a GUI for it. What I need to do is to display 5 images of recognized person. But I can only display one of them. The others are shown empty. Here is the code:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Test state")

def train_button():
    os.system('python3 extract_embeddings.py --dataset dataset --embeddings output/embeddings.pickle --detector face_detection_model --embedding-model openface_nn4.small2.v1.t7')
    os.system('python3 train_model.py --embeddings output/embeddings.pickle --recognizer output/recognizer.pickle --le output/le.pickle')
    messagebox.showinfo("INFO","Training completed")

def select_photo():
    global my_image
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="test",title ="Select a photo",filetypes=(("all files","*.*"),("png files","*.png"),("jpeg files","*.jpeg")))
    output = subprocess.check_output("python3 recognize.py --detector face_detection_model --embedding-model openface_nn4.small2.v1.t7 --recognizer output/recognizer.pickle --le output/le.pickle --image "+root.filename, shell=True)
    output = output.decode('utf-8')
    pic_name = output.split('\n')[0]
     
    my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/"+pic_name+"/"+pic_name+"1.jpeg"))
    my_image_label = Label(image = my_image).grid(row = 1 ,column = 0)

    name_label = Label(text = pic_name).grid(row=2,column=0)

    my_image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/"+pic_name+"/"+pic_name+"2.jpeg"))
    my_image_label1 = Label(image = my_image1).grid(row =1 ,column=1)

    my_image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/"+pic_name+"/"+pic_name+"3.jpeg"))
    my_image_label2 = Label(image = my_image2).grid(row = 1,column = 2)


button1 = Button(root,text = "Train" , command = train_button).grid(row=0 ,column=0)

button2 = Button(root,text = "Recognise from image", command = select_photo).grid(row = 0 ,column=1)



root.mainloop()
```

This is how the program shows images
[Resulting program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5Lbc.png)

**Thank you for your time**

Comment: `ImageTk.PhotoImage` has bug which removes it from memory when created in function and you have to assign to global variable. I see you use `global my_image` but you have to use also `global my_image1` and `global my_image2`

Comment: BTW: maybe instead of runnning `os.system` and `subprocess.check_output` you should do it in normal way and `import` script and run directly. But script may need to put code in functions and use `if __name__ == '__main__'` to get arguments from command line only when you run it in command line.

Comment: BTW: when you do `button1 = Button().grid()` then you assign `None` to variable because `grid()`/`pack()`/`place()` always return `None`. If you need this variable then you have to do it in two steps `button1 = Button(..)` and `button1.grid()`. The same with other widgets.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It worked. How can I display for example 20 images using for loop ? Do I have to make a label and assign global variable for each of them?

Comment: create global list for images and keep all of images in this list. OR create list for all `Label` and every image assign to own `Label `-- `my_image_label[1].photo = ...`

Comment: BTW: but you will have to create `Label` in two steps - `label = Label()` and later `label.grid()` - and then you can do `label.photo = image` and keep on list `all_labels.append(label)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bug in `PhotoImage` which removes image when it is assigned to local variable in function.

You have to assing it to global variable (it can be list if you have many images) or assign to widgets which you use to display it - `label.photo = image`

---

I can test it but here is version which uses `label.photo = image` to resolve this problem

It also uses `for`-loop to create labels and keep them on list.

But when you use `label.photo = image` then list is not necessary. List is only useful to access labels to remove old labels before you create new labels.

```
import tkinter as tk # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import filedialog

# --- functions ---

def train_button():
    os.system('python3 extract_embeddings.py --dataset dataset --embeddings output/embeddings.pickle --detector face_detection_model --embedding-model openface_nn4.small2.v1.t7')
    os.system('python3 train_model.py --embeddings output/embeddings.pickle --recognizer output/recognizer.pickle --le output/le.pickle')
    messagebox.showinfo("INFO","Training completed")

def select_photo():
    #global all_labels
    
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="test", title ="Select a photo", filetypes=(("all files","*.*"),("png files","*.png"),("jpeg files","*.jpeg")))
    output = subprocess.check_output("python3 recognize.py --detector face_detection_model --embedding-model openface_nn4.small2.v1.t7 --recognizer output/recognizer.pickle --le output/le.pickle --image "+root.filename, shell=True)
    output = output.decode('utf-8')
    pic_name = output.split('\n')[0]

    # remove previous labels
    for label in all_labels:
        label.destroy()
    
    for number in range(3):
        #filename = f"images/{pic_name}/{pic_name}{number+1}.jpeg" # f-string (Python 3.6+)
        filename = "images/{}/{}{}.jpeg".format(pic_name, pic_name, number+1) # (Python 2.7, 3.0+)
        
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename))
        
        label = tk.Label(image=image)
        label.photo = image   # assign to class variable to resolve problem with bug in `PhotoImage`
        
        label.grid(row=1, column=number)
        
        all_labels.append(label)

# --- main ---

all_labels = []

root = tk.Tk()

button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Train", command=train_button)
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Recognise from image", command=select_photo)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```